# Cross-compiling C project to PE32+ executable from within macOS using Clang

Tags: c, macos, clang, cross-compiling

I am currently attempting to cross-compile my C source code into a PE32+ executable, which hasn't yielded the greatest results.

I'm running macOS Ventura Beta 8 (macOS 13), using Clang which is bundled with LLVM (which was installed via the Homebrew tap).

Here is the command for compiling the source files:

```bash
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang \
    --target=x86_64-unknown-windows-gnu \
    -Wl,-e,_KernMain \
    -o kernel.o \
    src/Kernel/Kernel.c \
    src/Kernel/Memory/KernMem.c \
    src/Kernel/Graphics/KernGraphics.c \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Include/ \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Include/X64 \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/KernelOSPkg/src/Common \
    -I/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include \
    -L/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Library/ \
    -L/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib \
    -L/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/ldscripts \
    -L/usr/local/lib \
    -fuse-ld="/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/ld.lld"
```

It throws the following error:

```
lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc
lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc_eh
lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc
lld: error: unable to find library -lgcc_eh
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`CLANG info:`

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang --version
Homebrew clang version 15.0.2
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

`ld.lld info:`

```
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/ld.lld --version
Homebrew LLD 15.0.2 (compatible with GNU linkers)
```

Comment: Where did you obtain `Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32` from?  Does it have compiled library files with names ending in `.a`?  Does it have `libgcc.a` and `libgcc_eh.a` and if so, where?  Those are the two missing files that lld is trying to find.

Comment: Note that `-L/usr/local/lib` is almost certainly wrong because that directory would contain library files for macOS, not Windows.

Comment: Normally you shouldn't need to provide the path to compiler's standard libraries at all, it should find them on its own. You're compiler suite might not be configured/installed correctly.

Comment: @Aconcagua  The OP is just using a generic installation of LLVM for macOS, it probably doesn't ship with any libraries for Windows.

Comment: To answer the first question: there is a `libgcc_s.a`, but not `libgcc.a` nor `libgcc_eh.a` inside of `x86_64-w64-mingw32`; I have also removed the `-L/usr/local/lib` because I figured the same thing as you did. The compiler works fine (as far as I can tell) when compiling a regular C project as a Mach-O binary.

Furthermore, I have found `libgcc.a` and `libgcc_eh.a` at `~/Downloads/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0`. I'll see if including that directory helps.

Comment: That seems to have worked. Although, now it cannot find a symbol for `WinMain`, which is the common entry point name for a Windows application, IIRC. I'll see if I can define a custom entry name. Thank you everyone for answering! I'll post an answer if I manage to resolve the undefined symbol issue.

Comment: You shouldn't need to pass `/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/` to `-I` and `-L`. The only flag that's needed is `--sysroot=/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I didn't include the `/path/to/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/<version>` directory, which included the `libgcc.a` and `libgcc_eh.a` files.

Though, I still do not know how to resolve the issue with an *undefined symbol: WinMain*. I will update this answer if I find a solution.

Error in question:

```
ld.lld: error: undefined symbol: WinMain
>>> referenced by libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):(.text.startup)
clang-15: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Compilation command (does not compile successfully due to undefined symbol):

```bash
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang \
    -target x86_64-unknown-windows-gnu \
    -Wl,-e,KernMain \
    -fuse-ld=lld \
    -ffreestanding \
    -o kernel.o \
    src/Kernel/Kernel.c \
    src/Kernel/Memory/KernMem.c \
    src/Kernel/Graphics/KernGraphics.c \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Include/ \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Include/X64 \
    -I/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/KernelOSPkg/src/Common \
    -I/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include \
    -L/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.2.0 \
    -L/Users/kernel/Documents/edk2-master/edk2/MdePkg/Library/ \
    -L/Users/kernel/Downloads/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib \
    -fshort-wchar
```

EDIT: To fix the aforementioned error with the undefined symbol, simply supply `-nostdlib` to the compiler.